# Keep s3 folder private except for web application access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to protect a folder in my s3 architecture and only allow access to  the web app using an AWS access key

```
company
  production
  development
  private
```

If I put a DENY access directly on the private folder, then that DENY statement overrides all other bucket policies or IAM policies set for the web app.  Even if the web app has full admin access through an IAM policy, it will not be able to access the private folder if there is a DENY statement on that folder in the bucket policy.

I have tried the following bucket policy, but it still allows an anonymous user to look at files in the protected folder.

I thought all folders in a bucket are private unless stated in the bucket policy?

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::company/production/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "allow access to private files in the private folder",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::88888888888:user/web_app"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::company/*"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Its rather tricky to protect a folder within a bucket. Some clients don't handle restrictive policies all that well. Instead its easier to control access to the entire bucket or not. Anyone with admin access however, will be able to see the entire system.

Comment: The problem with that is I use CarrierWave to create images and do GET and POST requests to both public and private folders.  I believe when using CarrierWave and FOG, the initialize can only be associated with 1 bucket.

Comment: Could you please clarify the "problem" part of your question? For example, if you use the displayed Bucket Policy, how is your anonymous user attempting to access/view the files in the protected folder? Via CLI? URL? API? There is no obvious reason why they should be able to access files in the 'private' folder. Do you have any other permissions in place (eg IAM, or object-level)?

Comment: I accomplished what I needed with this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011035/unable-to-reproduce-aws-signature-from-example-using-hmac-sha256/30011166