# Unable to reproduce AWS signature from example using HMAC SHA256

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hmac

I am following this example

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

and trying to reproduce the 64 character string for the signature which they state as...

```
aeeed9bbccd4d02ee5c0109b86d86835f995330da4c265957d157751f604d404
```

I have successful matched the hex digeset for the Canonical Request and positive that the StringToSign string is correct.

The last piece is calculating the signing_key and signature.  This is where I am hitting a road block using the provided ruby function 'getSignatureKey'

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-ruby

```
signing_key = getSignatureKey secret_access_key, current_date, region, aws_service
signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', signing_key, string_to_sign)


 def getSignatureKey key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName
  kDate    = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', "AWS4" + key, dateStamp)
  kRegion  = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kDate, regionName)
  kService = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kRegion, serviceName)
  kSigning = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kService, "aws4_request")

  kSigning
end
```

The current output for 'signature' is this strange sequence of characters.

��ٻ���.�����h5��3 ��e�}wQ��

What am I missing to get the signature to equal...

```
aeeed9bbccd4d02ee5c0109b86d86835f995330da4c265957d157751f604d404
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your "strange sequence of characters" is in fact the correct output.

`OpenSSL::HMAC.digest` spits out a value represented in binary, and you are comparing that to a value represented in hex

Check to see what happens when you print out the signature after converting it to hex representation like so:

```
signature.each_byte.map { |b| "%02x" % b }.join
```

Comment: It is close, but there are three instance where a zero is missing.  I put an X in the following hex to demonstrate.  I wonder why the zeros are missing?  aeeed9bbccd4d02ee5c0109b86d86835f99533Xda4c265957d157751f6X4d4X4 vs

Comment: I see, that is easily fixable, will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your post but those are quite possibly exactly the same results, formatted differently.

Your code returns the raw result of the HMAC operation - this is arbitrary binary data so it's not going to print as anything readable. Amazon expect you to provide the hex representation for each byte: your first couple of bytes are "\xae\xee" instead of "aeee"

The easiest way to do this is call `hexdigest` rather than `digest`. Note that you should only do this for the final HMAC (when you sign the string to sign with the signing key) not when constructing the signing key

Comment: that did it.  thanks.  So by changing .digest to .hexdigest in the final calculation, i was able to get the correct hex     signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', signing_key, string_to_sign)